# picture by picture animation with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

is just for drawing an image on canvas, and I'd love to make a frame by frame animation, but so far my google haven't have any result or the answers were rather obscures. here is the code. of my javascript

```
<script>
      function drawOnCanvas() {
          var firstImg=1;
          var lastImg=75;
        var ctx=document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext('2d');
        var image=new Image();
        image.src="iglesiafls75.png";
        image.onload=function() {
          ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,550,800,0,0,550,800);
        }
      }

      window.addEventListener('load', drawOnCanvas, true);
    </script>
```

The image is part of 75 more and i'd like to know how to make then read in the canvas as it was a regular frame by frame animation, any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

1) don't get the canvas inside the function - that will go stupid slow.

```
// instead of
function () {
    var ctx = document.get......;
}

// do this
var ctx = document.getElement...
function draw () { ctx.drawImage(); }

// or
var ctx...
function draw (context) { context.drawImage(); }
draw(ctx);
```

It doesn't have to be global--just don't put it ***inside*** of the function that you're calling 60 times per second.

2) you can't do that with images. Pictures need to be 100% downloaded before they can be used.
The function you have will go by in a few 1/1000ths of a second. That's not even enough time to *start* downloading your image.

So make a loading system for your images, and when they're all loaded, *then* start your canvas animation.

3) in terms of managing image drawing, either you're going to switch between pictures every frame, or you're going to use an atlas of pictures, and switch coordinates to point at the proper section (like an animation strip, or a texture map).

4) to loop, you're going to use `window.requestAnimationFrame` (currently "webkitRequestAnimationFrame", mozRequest..., msRequest... ), or setTimeout.

Comment: var ctx=document.getElementById("mycanvas).getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
var firtImg=1;
var lastImg=75;

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) 
{
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) 
    {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
}
)();


function load(){
//loop here for loading system
if(firstImg< lastImg){
img.src = 'iglesiafls'+firstImg++'.png';
}





}

Comment: BTW I have this code, but it's not working do help me to see why please,